# Having issues using React Router 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I cannot comprehend how to use React Router properly. I want a component, rendered at the root (`"/"`) to have multiple routes and redirect to `"/projects"` by default. Routes that I want to have are these:

1. `"/projects"`
2. `"/projects/project/:projectId/"`
3. `"/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/"`
4. `"/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/task/:taskId/"`

Anyway, whatever I try, I cannot render anything past the second route despite link href matching the route path.

In a sense, I do not really want to have nested routes (at least not in the way they are implemented [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting), just replace components according to path instead of appending.

Here is [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-multiple-layout-forked-p2ky1x?file=/src/router/index.js:665-1410) link with one of many attempts.

Here are my routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from="/" to="/projects/" />

  <Route path="/projects/" exact>
    <p>List of projects.</p>

    <Link to="/projects/project/1/">Project #1</Link>
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId/">
    <p>List of devices</p>

    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1/">Device #1</Link>
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/">
    <p>List of tasks</p>

    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1/task/1/">Task #1</Link>
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/task/:taskId/">
    <p>Task info.</p>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by adding `exact` to the other routes.

Updated working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-multiple-layout-forked-6kkbxv)

The reason for this is `/projects/project/:projectId/` is the first matching route, even for a list of tasks because of the wildcard `:projectId`.

```
  <Route exact path="/projects/project/:projectId/">
    <p> List of devices </p>

    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1/"> Device #1 </Link>
  </Route>

  <Route exact  path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/">
    <p> List of tasks </p>

    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1/task/1/"> Task #1 </Link>
  </Route>

  <Route exact  path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/task/:taskId/">
    <p> Task info. </p>
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component that ***path order and specificity matters!*** Keep in mind that the `Switch` "Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location."

To resolve you should reorder the routes in inverse order of path specificity. In other words, you should try to match the ***more*** specific paths before the ***less*** specific paths. When done correctly it removes the need to sprinkle the `exact` prop all over the code.

***The `exact` prop is not necessary in about 99.9% of use cases.***

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId/task/:taskId">
    <p>Task info</p>
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId/device/:deviceId">
    <p>List of tasks</p>
    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1/task/1">Task #1</Link>
    ... other task links ...
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects/project/:projectId">
    <p>List of devices</p>
    <Link to="/projects/project/1/device/1">Device #1</Link>
    ... other device links ...
  </Route>

  <Route path="/projects">
    <p>List of projects</p>
    <Link to="/projects/project/1">Project #1</Link>
    ... other project links ...
  </Route>

  {/* Anything not handled above redirects to "/projects" */}
  <Redirect to="/projects" />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit having-issues-using-react-router-5]